# How to convert the TextClock as a Textview in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I want to develop an `application` for getting locations with time. So I have been writing code for displaying `Time` using TextClock tag. I need to display `Time` in `TextView`tag to store.
What is the method for this process?

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: `textView.setText(textClock.getText());`? What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: Actually i need to store  time  in SQLite DB for every minute.So i planned to display the time in a TextView. But i used TextClock tag to display the time.can i convert getting time in TextView .any idea? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
I found the solution for my question.

`

```
private String getDateTime() {
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        tv.setText(getDateTime()+"Lat" + location.getLatitude() + "Lon" + location.getLongitude());
    }
```

`